# Navigate to navigation controller from modal view navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I've been scratching my head to figure out how to navigate to my primary NavigationViewController (NVC) from a modal view which has a NVC of its own tied to a TableViewController (TVC).

I tried to segue but it is creating a new instance of the the VC

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToHomeFromMenuVC", sender: self)
```

My setup is ->NVC->VC1->VC2->VC3

All 3 VC's have one button which presents a side menu which is presented modally. This modal segue has a different NVC connected to a TVC. Upon clicking of either of 3 rows of TVC I'm trying to navigate to either VC1, VC2, or VC3 - but as of now I'm not being able to do it. I've created segues from the TVC to all 3 VC's which is part of the other NVC.

I'm using this third party library to make the menu VC which is the TVC. [Link](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu#code-less-storyboard-implementation)

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Typically you would structure your menu as the root view controller managing a container view and then the menu can just put the appropriate view controller into the container; it is basically a tab bar controller without the tab bar

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 I've update my post with the 3rd party tool that I'm using for the menu VC. Would it be possible for you to guide me? I'm using the section - Codeless Storyboard Implementation. Ty

Comment: Why do you want to put an additional navigation controller in place?  The side menu is already a navigation controller. Since the menu is pushing VC1, 2 or 3, these view controllers will need to manipulate the menu navigation controllers `viewControllers` property if they want to make themselves the root of the stack. I don't like side menus in general and while this one has some nice visuals, its use of a navigation controller rather than a containment approach means that you can't really maintain state between the various menu options